CMS Product-carousel, found 2 elements with non-unique
My homepage has different product-carousels (magento build-in) down the site. Some of the product-carousels has a few identical products/sku's.
Which result in this DOM error, since magento is assigning productnumber to html-IDs?

Do anyone know if this "bug" is fixed in newer versions of magento?
